# Have a nested parent model pointing to the first child model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My models are like this: **a discussion has_many posts** (nested resource).

I want to add a `starter_post_id` column to the `discussions` table, and have it record the 'thread starter post id'. The discussion is created along with the post in the nested form, and that when the logic should be called, because other posts to that discussion will be *replies* not *starter posts*.

I am not sure what I need to do after the `add_column` db migration.

1. Do I need a `belongs_to :post` in my Discussion model?
2. What's the order of creation for these nested objects. e.g. parent's creation ends before child's starts? or will the parent constructor call the child constructor?
3. Which model should the starter post assignment logic go to? This is related to Q2 since both objects needs to be initiated, but preferably before the DB call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried before_save and it won't work because at that point in time the discussion has no way to get hold of the starter post object. I was pointed out to use after_create instead.

```
def after_create
    self.starter_post_id = self.posts.first.id
    self.save!
end
```

This will cause one extra sql query, but it is better than doing it at the post model.

I used belongs_to so I can use `discussion.start_post_id`, but I guess it is optional.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the created_at field from you post model to determine the starter_post of a discussion. No need for any columns.

Add something like this in your discussion model

```
def starter_post
  self.posts.order("created_at ASC").first()
end
```

If you use this in you discussion.rb :

```
has_many :posts , :order => "created_at ASC"
```

you can then simply use :

```
def starter_post
  self.posts.first()
end
```

Comment: thanks, but sorry I forgot to mention that I needed to record this because I need to do a "title of 10 recent discussions". I want to reduce the number of SQL calls. (discussion title is taken from the starter post title)